# Add quotes around non-numeric atomic values in a JSON-like document

Tags: json, jq

I have a nested JSON-like document in the following format which I am trying to read using python. I am trying to put quotation marks (" ") around the non-numeric atomic values. I tried using python with a regular expression:

```
import re
valid_json = re.sub(r'(?<={|,)([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)(?=:)', r'"\1"', 
json_data)
```

The data file is like :

```
{
  "Attri1": 26789381,
  "Attri2": hjewvbfasnd3672183knsa,
  "Attri9": 457950,
  "Attri10": [
    {
      "NestedAtri1": vwebsn632871yb,
      "NestedAttri2": [
        {
          "A1": 0,
          "A2": ABB1,
          "A3": 30,
          "A5": [
            000,001
          ]
        },
        {
          "A1": 0,
          "A2": ABB1,
          "A3": 30,
          "A5": [
            000,001
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "NestedAtri1": rgdf3423,
      "NestedAttri2": [
        {
          "A1": 0,
          "A2": C,
          "A3": 50,
          "A5": [
            000,001
         ]
        },
        {
          "A1": 0,
          "A2": ABB1,
          "A3": 30,
          "A5": [
            000,001
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The expected output is with quotes around the values.

```
{
  "Attri1": 26789381,
  "Attri2": "hjewvbfasnd3672183knsa",
  "Attri9": 457950,
  "Attri10": [
    {
      "NestedAtri1": "vwebsn632871yb",
      "NestedAttri2": [
        {
          "A1": 0,
          "A2": "ABB1",
          "A3": 30,
          "A5": [
            "000,001"
          ]
        },
        {
          "A1": 0,
          "A2": "ABB1",
          "A3": 30,
          "A5": [
            "000,001"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "NestedAtri1": "rgdf3423",
      "NestedAttri2": [
        {
          "A1": 0,
          "A2": "C",
          "A3": 50,
          "A5": [
            "000,001"
         ]
        },
        {
          "A1": 0,
          "A2": "ABB1",
          "A3": 30,
          "A5": [
            "000,001"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any way I can add quotes using python/json or any other libraries. Or can I use jq filters to add quotes. 
Thanks

Comment: Unless your goal is to write your own parser, you are likely better off finding a JSON parsing library than trying to get this regular expression working.

Comment: Please follow the mcve guidelines and show the expected output.

Comment: By the way, the input as shown is not JSON.  Can you perhaps modify the program or process that produced the pseudo-JSON so that it produces valid JSON or something else that follows a well-known standard?

Comment: @peak Okay. I edited my question.

Comment: @jenny - What process is producing this mishmash? Also it's not completely clear why you're adding quotation marks around some values but not others, e.g. why does A5's value become ["000","001"] rather than "[000,001]" or ["000,001"] or indeed [0,1] ?

Comment: @peak I want to add quotation marks around all the values of the object. If the numbers don't have the quotes they are still parsed. Whereas the combination of string and numbers need quotes around them. And A5's value is ["000,001"]. But if it function can filter it as ["000","001"], that should also be fine.

Comment: It's not json, you can't claim it's json, it's not. If you want to fix the data, you need to fix the process that generated that. Jq is designed to read and process json data which that is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an awk script which will handle your example and others like it, but it is NOT robust.  For example, it won't handle keys with embedded spaces properly.

```
awk '
   function ws(line,  s) {
     s=line; sub(/[^    ].*/, "", s);
     return s;
   }

   # Global: $0
   # print a value with quotation marks, checking for punctuation
   function printit(s,  w) {
     if ( s ~ /^[\[{]$/ ) { print $0; return}
     w=s; sub(/,$/, "", w);
     printf "\"%s\"", w;
     if (w != s) {printf "%s", ","}
     print "";
   }

   NF==1 && ($1 ~ /^[][{}],?$/) { print; next }
   NF==2 && ($2 ~ /^[][{}],?$/) { print; next }
   NF==2 && ($2 ~ /^[0-9]+,?$/) { print; next } 
   NF==2 && ($2 ~ /^".*",?/   ) { print; next } 

   # key: value
   $1 ~ /^".*":$/ {
     printf "%s", ws($0) $1 " ";
     $1=""; sub(/^ /,"",$0); printit($0);
     next;
   }

   NF == 1 {
     printf "%s", ws($0);  # indentation
     printit($1);
     next;
   }
   {print}
'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works perfectly except it even adds quotes at the beginning and at the end. Example if the json file is as                         
   { "Atrr1" : hvbd5263127 } the output comes up as "{"Atrr1" : "hvbd5263127" }"

Comment: Your new example does not conform with the formatting of the example in the Q.